# Is there a snippet plugin compatible with Supertab?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, plugin-supertab, plugin-snipmate

I used Suptertab for a while and I really like it. Recently I tried to add a snippet management plugin but I wasn't successful in getting them to work with Supertab. I tried SnipMate and Ultisnips. Does anyone have a suggestion on which plugin to use? I really don't want to change the shortcut for any one of them and I hope it works for both.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean [Ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715), rather than Ultsnippets

Answer (score 1):

guess you need autocompleter+snippet plugin, since Supertab will be slow when the tags file are large, recommand you two group plugins:

- (1) YouCompleteMe + UltiSnips
- (2) Neocomplete + clang_complete + Jedi + neosnippet + neosnippet-snippets

They are the best C/C++/Python completer+snippet plugin combinations I ever used, but incompatible with each other.

YCM group is fast, easy to install on both Windows and Linux, big (450MB), good to use, you need to learn how to write a '.ycm_extra_conf.py' for your own project.

Neocomplete group is smooth, good, but need lua support. AFAIK, vim-gnome already support lua compiled with vim/gvim on many Linux(Fedora/Ubuntu/etc), but I don't use it for a long time.

Here's my vimrc: https://github.com/zhaochenyou/vimrc

It support many plugins, very good to use, it based on Vundle, YouCompleteMe, ctags, cscope, the_silver_searcher/ag.

you may need the Installation guide of YCM: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

Comment: you forget that for neovim users we have deoplete instead of neoplete (no need for lua, use python), but it's the same, deoplete+neosnippets in this case, my neovim config is this: https://gitlab.com/snippets/25691